# How to make text update dynamically in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, core-data

I found a problem where the number of cards in the "stack" of cards is static and doesn't change as the cards are being removed. Is there a way the number of cards could be dynamic and change as the cards are being removed? I suppose the main problem is with how am I displaying it, in my approach, I'm simply using `Text("Number of Cards: \(set.cardsArray.count)")`
Here's the FlashcardSetView where all of the cards are being displayed:

```
struct FlashcardSetView: View {

@FetchRequest(
    entity: FlashCardData.entity(),
    sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \FlashCardData.date, ascending: false)],
    predicate: NSPredicate(format: "cardStatus == %d", 3) // Fetch cards with category 3
)
var categoryThreeCards: FetchedResults<FlashCardData>

var set: FlashSets
@ObservedObject var dataController = DataController.shared
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
@State private var showTermDefinitionView = false
@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss

@State private var currentlySelectedCard: FlashCardData?
@State var isLearned = false //1
@State var isThink = false  //2
@State var isHard = false   // 3
@State var isRepeat = false // 4
@State private var studyPhase: StudyPhase = .initial
@State var currentCardIndex = 0
@State private var toEndView = false


var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        ZStack {
            
            
            Text("Card list is empty")
                .offset(y: -50)
            
            if studyPhase == .initial {
                ForEach(set.cardsArray, id: \.self) { card in
                    
                    VStack {
                        Text("Number of Cards: \(set.cardsArray.count)") // !displays the number of cards
                            .font(.headline)
                        SingleFlashCard(cards: set.cardsArray,
                                        removal: {
                            withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
                                removeCurrentCard()
                            }
                            print("Removing card with animation")
                        }, currentCardIndex: $currentCardIndex, isLearned: $isLearned,
                                        isThink: $isThink,
                                        isHard: $isHard,
                                        isRepeat: $isRepeat)
                        .transition(.asymmetric(insertion: .opacity, removal: .opacity))
                    }
                    .onAppear {
                        currentlySelectedCard = card
                        // Automatically transition to the EndView when all cards are studied
                        
                    }
                }
            }
            private func removeCurrentCard() {
                if studyPhase == .initial {
                    if currentCardIndex < set.cardsArray.count - 1 {
                        currentCardIndex += 1 // Move to the next card
                        currentlySelectedCard = set.cardsArray[currentCardIndex] // Update currentlySelectedCard
                    } else {
                        if set.cardsArray.isEmpty {
                            // All cards in the set have been studied
                            toEndView = true // Transition to the EndView
                        } else {
                            studyPhase = .hard // Transition to the "hard" study phase if there are more cards
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

SingleFlashCard - a view for single card:

```
struct SingleFlashCard: View {
let card: FlashCardData
var removal: (() -> Void)? = nil

@State var term = ""
@State var definition = ""
@Binding var isLearned: Bool
@Binding var isThink: Bool
@Binding var isHard: Bool
@Binding var isRepeat: Bool

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25, style: .continuous)
            .fill(Color.white)
        //.offset(x: isLearned ? 500 : 0)
        //.overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25).stroke(getColor(), lineWidth: 2))// Here we change the border color based on the swipe direction
            .shadow(radius: 3)
        
        VStack {
            NavigationStack {
                
                Text(card.term ?? "Unnamed Card")
                    .offset(y: -100)
                Divider()
                if isTapped {
                    Text(card.definition ?? "Unnamed Card")
                        .offset(y: 100)
                }
            }
            
            
        }
        
        
    }
    .frame(width: 300, height: 500)
}
```

}

[image: FlashCardData entity]
[image: FlashSets entity]

Comment: In `FlashcardSetView`, have you tried using `@Binding var set: FlashSets` and pass it with `FlashcardSetView(set: $set)`, where you declare `@State var set: FlashSets = ....` in the parent View. Note I don't see `cardsArray` as part of the `FlashSets` in your coredata.

Comment: thank you for answer, the cardsArray is in the extension for Entity: `var cardsArray: [FlashCardData] {
            let cardsArray = cards?.allObjects as? [FlashCardData] ?? []
            return cardsArray
        }`

Comment: Note, in your `func removeCurrentCard()` you are not removing any cards from `set.cardsArray`. But you expect the `Text("Number of Cards: \(set.cardsArray.count)") ` to change, is this really logical? In any case when you remove cards in your code, you should remove them from its source, not from the `cardsArray` computed property. Note also `NavigationView` is deprecated, use `NavigationStack` instead.

Comment: I see now, I would change the code for the remove method then